# Select tail of a bone with Python

Tags: python, scripting, bones

I am new to python and need to select the tail of a bone in edit mode with python. I was used this script but it doesn’t select the tail of a bone:

```
bpy.data.armatures["Armature"].bones["Bone.001"].select_tail=True
```

So i need help to select the tail of a bone in edit mode with python code.

Any helps are very very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is, but selecting stuff in edit mode only works using bpy.ops.select_all() or execute the code in *object mode* and the switch back to edit mode. 
where ob is my armature object:
`ob.data.bones['Bone'].select_tail = True`
works if you're in object mode and then press tab in the viewport.

```
import bpy
arm = bpy.data.armatures['Armature']
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT') # .select only has an effect in object mode (don't ask me why)
for bone in arm.bones: # deselect the other bones
    bone.select = False
    bone.select_tail = False
    bone.select_head = False

arm.bones['Bone'].select_tail = True
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT') # go back to Edit Mode, to see the results
```

Comment: your script works one time perfectly and doesn't work again. I get eror `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ob' is not defined`
This is your script i have used
`ob.data.bones['Bone'].select_tail = True`
any helps ?

Comment: Nobody to help ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. ob is your armature object. Use your code in object mode, then switch to edit.

Comment: @ Frederik Steinmetz can I have the full code iam new to python

Comment: I did so, couldn't do it before today, bc. I was not in front of a computer.

Comment: @ Frederik Steinmetz I'am glad thanks it working perfectly

Comment: @ Frederik Steinmetz can i have you on facebook please !!!

Comment: We're on Facebook, BlenderDiplom. I hardly ever check my personal page.

Comment: ok can you help me more because I need to hide all armatures with it bones with à python script please